WSO2 Micro Integrator: How to handle "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal" content-type from backend?
I'm trying to handle responses with content-type "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal" from a backend service in WSO2 Micro Integrator but facing issues.
[2024-10-29 11:05:53,099] ERROR {JsonStreamBuilder} - Error occurred while processing document for application/json java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

What I've already tried:
I've added the following configurations to deployment.toml:
[[custom_message_builders]]
content_type = "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal"
class = "org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder"

[[custom_message_formatters]]
content_type = "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal"
class = "org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder"

but still the same issue.
Full Wirelog

[2024-10-30 09:27:58,660] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2
<< "POST /api/data/v9.2/ext_ext_CreatePhoneCall
HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender
I/O dispatcher-2 << "Authorization: Bearer
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjNQYUs0RWZ5Qk5RdTNDdGpZc2EzWW1oUTVFMCIsImtpZCI6IjNQYUs0RWZ5Qk5RdTNDdGpZc2EzWW1oUTVFMCJ9.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.MZ01OCU7mHnTqFqjDXM7cJo8HQexKV9jazLzaO_FLF-OswNOTUYSfkERCGFKpuoDnCdcPoeB8fRZFLVrEgHklKOxgpkxELTr9i87vE-5_Hhc8GgROnOggjJt27hrR6EL9-QgUZVZw1gYNc50Kvc-RPOh8ilMlR7oHOec30BXmKHlbpm0oSZyvaAID-9FLIaKWXXyzD4xPK9g4qo7Bxz0fVpJb1Mb8y9o10Su7khOr91jOqNz5HNVNmXzIzslVZEBqH79eV3VVP5i5E-KUo-nrfmuxSJNSQGUfshW2J3XNcccgejvBp8a9vVIssBL9BS_X6mdFhkxNbs1lKjy6Fp_BA[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30
09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Cookie:
ARRAffinity=fdc24e542b5d23d48207094ef629ea335496eef801a076475a9de27e667b06ef5ab954b42cfa12ad9f33ddc80a07e15dd633bd57139a65479392e46e5242529408DCF808F8779371266646687;
ReqClientId=9a2bf262-a488-4e53-9ae3-f8b1bce5f9ba;
orgId=aae74ad2-91b6-44ac-82ae-6298a713baa6[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30
09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 <<
"activityid: 91cb5c40-08bb-4f22-ab6c-34d2301f8705[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30
09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Accept:
/[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Postman-Token:
a24c4335-152b-4c63-aea1-7d8534c64070[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,661]
DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire} -
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Content-Type:
application/json[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire} -
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Content-Length:
71[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O
dispatcher-2 << "Host:
topnet-recette.crm4.dynamics.com[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,661]
DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Connection:
Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire} -
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "User-Agent:
Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,661] DEBUG
{wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30
09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 <<
"{[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O
dispatcher-2 << "    "direction": "0",[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30
09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "
"tel_num" : "73247703",[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,661] DEBUG {wire}

HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "    "guid":""[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,662] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 <<
"}"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,991] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O
dispatcher-2 >> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992]
DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Cache-Control:
no-cache[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender
I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Allow: OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30
09:27:58,992] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >>
"Content-Type: application/json;
odata.metadata=minimal[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992] DEBUG {wire}
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Encoding: br[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O
dispatcher-2 >> "Expires: -1[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992] DEBUG
{wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Vary:
Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992] DEBUG {wire} -
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Set-Cookie:
ARRAffinity=fdc24e542b5d23d48207094ef629ea335496eef801a076475a9de27e667b06efeb29bb4b19df1459d2ea781b605f33064b9fea1f144b525b9d7676625c4ffb5408DCF8C0F5FD3665266646687;
path=/; secure; HttpOnly[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992] DEBUG
{wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "x-ms-service-request-id:
a43cef86-de04-4952-8a06-b0db5a01324e[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992]
DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >>
"Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992] DEBUG {wire} -
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "REQ_ID:
a43cef86-de04-4952-8a06-b0db5a01324e[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992]
DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "CRM.ServiceId:
CRMAppPool[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992] DEBUG {wire} -
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "AuthActivityId:
6ee0d391-3657-44ab-a023-3f1a6871d564[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992]
DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "x-ms-dop-hint:
48[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O
dispatcher-2 >> "x-ms-ratelimit-time-remaining-xrm-requests:
1,200.00[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender
I/O dispatcher-2 >> "x-ms-ratelimit-burst-remaining-xrm-requests:
7999[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,992] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O
dispatcher-2 >> "OData-Version: 4.0[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,993]
DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "X-Source:
2202161391929254157899124520593117161611971222081891371477915820430165632710228134158[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30
09:27:58,993] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Public:
OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,993] DEBUG {wire} -
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "X-Source:
60157198249183334312291322451725383015478177522359514080195737118651511775289[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30
09:27:58,993] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Date:
Wed, 30 Oct 2024 08:28:01 GMT[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,993] DEBUG
{wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Length:
400[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,993] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O
dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]"[2024-10-30 09:27:58,993] DEBUG {wire} -
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >>
"[0x1b][0x97][0x2][0x0][0xe4][0xb2][0xcd]^[0xff]=y[0x11][0x5]?Q[0xcb][\r][0x93][0x92][0xad][0x6][0x19][0x9a][0x8a][0x1d]\S[0xf4][\r][0x9f][0xf9][0xee]#[0x93]z[0x15][0x9c]8[0xd4]Y[0xda][0x3][\r][0xf7]f[0x8b]qD[0xbd][0x9b][0xd3][0xf2]$[0x8][0x1b][0x95]+8[0xae][0x93]Y.[0xe8][0xaf][0xdd][0xdb]s[0xe7][0xc4][0xe0]%[0x93][0xdd]T[0xe8]H[0x8b][0x5]:[0x87][0xb4]h[0xcb][0x80][0x92][0x13][0xc7]<[0x17][0xba][0x19]0[0xfc]E6M[0xa9]d[0xdb]i[0x1e]Poo[0xbd]3v[0xe8]9[0xca][0xde][0xd9][0xeb][0x3][0xc5][0xb9][0xcb][0xeb][0xf7][0xb3][0x16][0xb5][0xc3][0xe7]~][0xe1][0x99][0xb6][0xf6][0x15]?d_#x[0xb0]>[0x81][0x98][0xdf][0xf7]Z^hks[0xc6][0x1f]@[0x6]+[0x5]O[\r][0xb6][0xa6][0xc2][0xe0]e[\n]"[2024-10-30
09:27:58,993] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >>
"[0xb2]U[0x9][0xce]jsf([0x8][0x8][0x9d][0x2]O[0x81][0xf2][0x11]@[0xf3][0x8b]Gt3~[0x1b]![0xba][0x13]+f[0x99]%[0xd5][0xc6]S[0xe0]0w[0xb0]%-[0x9f]<F[0x84][0x1f][0xaf][0xf7][0xc4]N#[0x9b][0xff][0x95]zPQ=n[0xe6]G[0xba]i[0x6][0xe6]
)xb[0xd2]0
[0xb1]H[0x91]![0x4][0xe9][0x4][0x9c][0x13][0xce][0xb9][0xf1]u'[0xe][0x82][0x4]w[0x1b][0xdd][0xc3][0xb0][0xb3][0x84][0x95][0x1b][0xb8][0x85][0x6][0x9b]]t[0xd5][0x81]H[0xa0][0xfd]lw[0xe][0x82][0x0][0xbb][0x9a].I[0x93]4"[0xd8][0x15][0x82]$:[0xd2][0x84]s)[0x83]$[0xd5][0xb2]+[0x12]v[0xe7][0xce][0xec][0x0]+g[0xdd][0x8b][\n]"[2024-10-30
09:27:58,993] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >>
"[0xb2][0xbf][0x95][0x2]u[0x83]o!C[0xe5][0x97]F;[0x17]lM[0xa9]
[0xcd][0xa9][0xb6]f[0xd0][0xa9][0xa5]:p[0xc7][0xa1][0xb0][0x18]T[0xdb][0x91][0x10]i[0x1c]0xf0[0xd8][0xfc]o6[0xb0][0x1]"[2024-10-30
09:27:59,000] ERROR {JsonStreamBuilder} - Error occurred while
processing document for application/json
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method)   at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  at
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)    at
org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder.processDocument(JsonStreamBuilder.java:69)  at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:153)    at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:174)   at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:127)   at
org.apache.synapse.transport.util.PassThroughMessageHandler.buildMessage(PassThroughMessageHandler.java:103)  at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:155) at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:96)   at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:242) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:825) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:324) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:644) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:219)   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)  at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:304) at
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)Caused by:
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: #Can not parse stream. MessageID:
urn:uuid:f3f4ae42-3fbb-4cb7-8cd4-22388e0a45d2. Error>>>
#getNewJsonPayload. Could not save JSON payload. Invalid input stream found. Payload is not a JSON string.    at
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:888) at
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder.processDocument(JsonStreamBuilder.java:43)  ...
22 moreCaused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: #getNewJsonPayload.
Could not save JSON payload. Invalid input stream found. Payload is
not a JSON string.    at
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:872) ...
23 more  [2024-10-30 09:27:59,000] ERROR {DeferredMessageBuilder} -
Error building message org.apache.axis2.AxisFault at
org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder.processDocument(JsonStreamBuilder.java:73)  at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:153)    at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:174)   at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:127)   at
org.apache.synapse.transport.util.PassThroughMessageHandler.buildMessage(PassThroughMessageHandler.java:103)  at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:155) at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:96)   at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:242) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:825) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:324) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:644) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:219)   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)  at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:304) at
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)  [2024-10-30
09:27:59,001]  WARN {RelayUtils} - Server encountered an error, the
request message will be consumed and discarded, , CLIENT_ADDRESS =
/127.0.0.1:50430, Correlation ID =
91cb5c40-08bb-4f22-ab6c-34d2301f8705[2024-10-30 09:27:59,001] ERROR
{RelayUtils} - Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault    at
org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder.processDocument(JsonStreamBuilder.java:73)  at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:153)    at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:174)   at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:127)   at
org.apache.synapse.transport.util.PassThroughMessageHandler.buildMessage(PassThroughMessageHandler.java:103)  at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:155) at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:96)   at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:242) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:825) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:324) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:644) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:219)   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)  at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:304) at
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)  [2024-10-30
09:27:59,001] ERROR {SequenceMediator} - {api:apicrm} Error while
building message. Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream   at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:458)    at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:221)   at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:127)   at
org.apache.synapse.transport.util.PassThroughMessageHandler.buildMessage(PassThroughMessageHandler.java:103)  at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:155) at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:96)   at
org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:242) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:825) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:324) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:644) at
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:219)   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)  at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:304) at
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)Caused by:
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault    at
org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder.processDocument(JsonStreamBuilder.java:73)  at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:153)    at
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:174)   ...
15 more



is it possible to share the full error stack trace along with the sample response message? It would be great if you can share the wire logs to check response from the backend

I have update my question with the wirelog

It seems the backend sends data which is encoded using Brotli compression. Let's try to remove the accept-encoding header and see whether we can resolve the issue. Before calling the backend, let's add below property.
  <header action="remove" name="Accept-Encoding" scope="transport"/>


Based on the log provided, the JsonStreamBuilder has been correctly selected as the intended builder for the specified content type. The issue now seems to lie with the actual payload that the builder is attempting to parse. Therefore, please first validate that the received payload is a valid JSON format.

I thin that can be problem with encoding br. You can try set in header: Accept-Encoding: gzip I will also try to set:
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>

